# Error loading RubyGems plugin. cannot load such file

Tags: ruby, rubygems, homebrew, compass-sass

So when I'm trying to install compass via terminal I get the following error.

```
> gem install compass
Ignoring gem-wrappers-1.4.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine gem-wrappers --version 1.4.0
Error loading RubyGems plugin "/Users/collinvanderveer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/gem-wrappers-1.4.0/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": cannot load such file -- gem-wrappers (LoadError)
    Compass is charityware. If you love it, please donate on our behalf at http://umdf.org/compass Thanks!
Successfully installed compass-1.0.3
Parsing documentation for compass-1.0.3
Done installing documentation for compass after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

I have installed homebrew 2.2.6 and npm 6.13.7

not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Do you try what the error message tells you to do, running `gem pristine gem-wrappers --version 1.4.0`?

Comment: I've overseen that thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should try to uninstall ruby 2.6.3 and re-install it.

```
rvm uninstall ruby-2.6.3
```

and then

```
rvm install ruby-2.6.3
```